# keras imagedatagenerator don't use partial batch

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras

I am using keras imagedatagenerator (in the tf api), with python 3 over anaconda, and trying to use imagedatagenerator.flow_from_directory()

The number of images is not evenly devided in the number of images in a batch, I need to leave the last - partial batch out of the training, if I could tell imagedatagenerator just to leave random n images out in order to keep all the batches in the same size, this is also ok.

How can this be done?

Thanks